# Raw css not being loaded in my bundle.js Angular 2 app

Tags: css, angular, webpack

I have been searching to find a solution to my problem, but could not find why my css is not being loaded. 
I have a simple Angluar 2 app that is requiring html and css in the components. 
The webpack is doing the bundling and creates the bundle.js of the html, and js files. However, it does not load the css files inside the bundle. Instead of my actual css it puts:

```
function(module, exports) {
    module.exports = "// style-loader: Adds some css to the DOM by adding a <style> tag\n\n// load the styles\nvar content = require(\"!!./../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./print.css\");\nif(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];\n// add the styles to the DOM\nvar update = require(\"!./../../node_modules/style-loader/addStyles.js\")(content, {});\nif(content.locals) module.exports = content.locals;\n// Hot Module Replacement\nif(module.hot) {\n\t// When the styles change, update the <style> tags\n\tif(!content.locals) {\n\t\tmodule.hot.accept(\"!!./../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./print.css\", function() {\n\t\t\tvar newContent = require(\"!!./../../node_modules/css-loader/index.js!./print.css\");\n\t\t\tif(typeof newContent === 'string') newContent = [[module.id, newContent, '']];\n\t\t\tupdate(newContent);\n\t\t});\n\t}\n\t// When the module is disposed, remove the <style> tags\n\tmodule.hot.dispose(function() { update(); });\n}"/***/ }
```

here is the related to css parts of my webpack.config file I am using:

```
{
                test:  /\.css$/,  
                loader: 'raw'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,  
                loader: 'style!css'
            },
            {
                test:/\.gif|png/, loader: "file-loader"    
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw'
            }
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json','.css', '.html']
    }
```

and in my component i am simply requiring the html and css files.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [require('./my.css')],
    template: require('./my.html')
})
```

The text put in the bundle.js is like the loader could not find the css files, but they are at the same relative path as my html files that are being loaded.

Does anybody know what could be the issue?

Appreciate any suggestion, I am at loss by trying different things.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out a problem that solved my problem, at least one of them. 
I needed to exclude the css under my serverd folder like:

```
{
   test: /\.css$/,  
   loader: 'style!css,
   exclude: /app/
}
```

So this way those css wont be picked up by styler and loader because, I think, angular needs a list of text as the CSS. 
So this solved my problem.

But I still have an issue, that I have a hack for it but I don't like it.
Before changing my app to use webpack as bundler, I was using npm and system.js (as is documented on angular.io site). So I had a global css in my index.html that did the overall styling of my app. But after changing to webpack obviously could not reference global style in index.html as before. To get the global styling work over all of my app I changed the ViewEncapsulation mode to None (encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None). This works but I don't like it, it does not seem right, and I am afraid down the road bite me.

Does anybody know how to require my global css for all the app? 
I have found a way but for some reason does not work.
I tried ExtractTextPlugin but was not able to get it work.

```
{
    test: /\.css$/,  
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader'),
    exclude: /app/
}
```

and added to my plugin:

```
plugins: [
new ExtractTextPlugin("./glob.css")
]
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong?

Thanks